# iText signature image doesn't appear on iphone or dropbox preview

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm working in a personal project that involves iText for the task of signing documents.

Currently, I want to add a certificate to a pdf document and give it an image appearance. At this moment, my code is like this:

```
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

    appearance.setReason(reason);
    appearance.setLocation(location);
    appearance.setContact(contactNumber);

    appearance.setSignatureGraphic(
            Image.getInstance(signatureSrcPath)
    );

    appearance.setVisibleSignature(
          new Rectangle(left, top, left + width, top - height), page, null
    );

    appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
```

With that appearance, I proceed to sign the document digitally with the following code:

```
  MakeSignature.signDetached(
        appearance,
        new BouncyCastleDigest(),
        signature,
        chain,
        crlList,
        null,
        tsaClient,
        0,
        MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS
    );
```

And it works! The document is signed digitally with my certificate and the signature picture is displayed. That's ok.

**My problem here is, if I open this pdf with iphone, or I upload the pdf to dropbox and preview it, the certificate picture doesn't appear.**

I don't know why this is happening, a bit of help here would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a viewer issue. Which viewer are you using? Not all viewers have a signature panel. Some viewers didn't implement annotations. What you see in Adobe Reader on the desktop is a widget annotation corresponding with the signature field. If a PDF reader doesn't support that functionality, you won't see anything (but that doesn't mean the signature isn't there).

Comment: As @Bruno said, numerous incomplete viewers don't display annotations, especially pre-viewers and also especially Apple viewers. If you want a visual hint of the signature in such viewers, too, you might consider adding the image to the content in the same position. Beware, though, this it's not allowed if the PDF already has prior signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  @Bruno, I was doing the tests with dropbox visor. The fact is, I want to add an image every time the document is signed digitally. I take the appearance approach since if I use a normal image, the current signatures will be invalidated every time an image is added...   Is there another way to do this with iText? Thank you!

Comment: What you need to do is you sign your document each time and add a signature image for each signature (you have to do that in the append mode and then your previous signatures are not invalidated). If you want to view your document in a different viewer you should flatten your form fields (including signatures). Then most viewers should be able to display your document correctly...

Comment: Yeah, but If I flatten all the forms, the digitall signatures will be lost, I think. At this moment, I'm doing a signature with appearance in append mode  as you said, my problem is this appearance doesn't appear in some previews.